# LibGdx TextButtonStyle Offset not working correctly

Tags: libgdx, animation, gui

I'm intending to give an animation to the `TextButton` by giving the `pressedOffsetX` and `pressedOffsetY` values:

```
TextButtonStyle buttonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
buttonStyle.font = font25;
buttonStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
buttonStyle.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(settingsAtlas.findRegion("achievements"));
buttonStyle.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(settingsAtlas.findRegion("achievements"));
buttonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 5;
buttonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -5;
```

And I created a button like this:

```
TextButton achievementsButton = new TextButton("ACHIEVEMENTS", buttonStyle);
achievementsButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        // show achievements
    }
});
```

But when I click the button, only the text in it is animated. The button background stays in the same position. What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe offset only effects the children of the button. Do it works correctly.

Comment: @Menno Gouw Oh! That's too bad. It woked for `ImageButton`, but I now I guess it's because the image was the child of the button?

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says offset only effects the children, i.e the text inside the button.

What you need to look at is this piece of code:

```
buttonStyle.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(settingsAtlas.findRegion("achievements"));
buttonStyle.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(settingsAtlas.findRegion("achievements"));
```

Since you set the same image for `up` and `down` you wont see any change on the actual button when you click it. You need to change `down` to whatever color or image you want to show on click, giving it an animation effect.

If you want the actual button to 2move" like the text inside it, well I don't think libdx has any built in methods for that.

Comment: Yeah I guess changing the up and down images is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry yesterday I was a wreck :) but I just found a solution for you. Simply build up the button yourself... lol, I cannot believe I didn't think of that yesterday?

```
Button button = new Button();
        button.setDebug(true);
        Button.ButtonStyle style = new Button.ButtonStyle();
        style.pressedOffsetX = 100;
        Label label = new Label("Touch me!", skin);
        button.add(label);
        button.setStyle(style);

        button.addListener(new ClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
            {
                System.out.println("I moved with label background and text of label");
            }
        });

        table.add(button);
```

You can add any actor you want to the button since it's actually a table with a click state. Anything within the button should be offset and thus you can put a label with background like I did, a stack with an image and label on top or even multiple tables inside the button.

So in your case you just need to setup a label with your text and use your achievements region as the background or seperate image. Put those in your custom made button and you are set.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. The same problem as `TextButton` - only the text is moving, not the button background.